# Format a time span as a number of days, hours and minutes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is purely an Excel sheet question.

I have a time span that is basically a difference between two cells, each containing a date:

I have managed to get the time difference in number of hours and minutes by changing the number format to `[h]:mm`. Now I would like to get the difference in number of days, hours and minutes. I tried to set the number format to `[d]:[h]:[mm]` but it is not accepted by Excel.

Here's what I have now:

```
    A                   B                   C (=A2-A1)
    ----------------    ----------------    ----------
1|  14/10/2011 00:00    17/10/2011 07:50    79:50
2|  14/10/2011 00:00    17/10/2011 11:00    83:00
```

Here's what I would like to get:

```
    A                   B                   C (=A2-A1)
    ----------------    ----------------    ----------
1|  14/10/2011 00:00    17/10/2011 07:50    3:7:50
2|  14/10/2011 00:00    17/10/2011 11:00    3:11:00
```

How can I do that? Is there a number format available for that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `TEXT`
=`TEXT(B1-A1,"d:h:mm")`

Note the same effect can be achieved using a simple number format on the cells directly

- select your range (cells `C1, C2` etc)
- right click and *Format Cells*
- *Custom*
- Type `d:hh:mm`

If unlike your example data, your date differences exceed 31 days, then an approach such as
`=INT(B1-A1)&":"&TEXT(B1-A1,"h:mm")`
will work

Comment: Nice, and I would use `TEXT(B1-A1; IF(B1-A1>1; "d:hh:mm"; "h:mm"))` to get days number only if the time difference is superior to one day.

Comment: @tosh what do you mean it is not accepted by Excel?

Comment: @Toshe: use TEXT(B1-A1; "d:h:m")

Answer (score 9):

Warning: the above only works for ranges less than 31 days.
use

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(FLOOR(B1-A1,1),"@")," Days",TEXT(B1-A1," h:mm:ss"))
```

instead for ranges above 31 days. This will not sort well, so it would be better to do the calculation in one column and then prettify that column for the end result.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for, when I came here from Google. But it should be "FLOOR(B1-A1,0)" instead, why do you want to keep the fractional part of days?

Comment: I get a #DIV/0! if I use FLOOR(<anything>,0).  The second parameter is 'significance', not 'number of decimal places to keep'.  You could provide '0.1' or '0.01' successfully to keep decimal places, but not '0' to eliminate them.  In this case, '1' is correct as it FLOOR's to the nearest '1'.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately it appears number and datetime formats cannot be combined, otherwise a custom format of:

```
0:h:m
```

would be the ticket.  However, if for spans of 32 days or more, you are satisfied with just displaying the number of (fractional) days you can use a custom format like:

```
[>=32] 0.00 "days"; d:h:m
```

The cell value remains numeric.

Comment: Actually this works best for me, but for the sake of confusion aversion due to `##:##:##` format is usually seen as `hh:mm:ss`, I used the following: `[>=32] 0.00 "days";[<1] h:m:s; d h:m:s`, This format translates to `34.25 days`, `4 15:44:10`,and `2:15:33`.

Answer (score 0):

The following is certainly not the shortest formula and not a direct answer to the question but works to show the correct result (also on LibreOffice) in the following format:

# days ## hours ## minutes ## seconds

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(FLOOR(B2-A2,1),"@")," days ", IF(HOUR(A12)-HOUR(A11)<0,HOUR(A12)-HOUR(A11)+24,HOUR(A12)-HOUR(A11))," hours ",IF(MINUTE(A12)-MINUTE(A11)<0,MINUTE(A12)-MINUTE(A11)+60,MINUTE(A12)-MINUTE(A11)), " minutes ", TEXT(B2-A2,"s"), " seconds")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following approach works as well, assuming that your start date is in cell C2 and your end date is in cell D2:

```
 =TEXT((D2-C2)-MOD(D2-C2,1),"0") & " days " & TEXT(MOD(D2-C2,1),"hh:mm")
```

Comment: `(D2-C2)-MOD(D2-C2,1)` can be simplified to just `INT(D2-C2)` isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

`=IFERROR(INT(Date1-Date2)&" Days "&INT(MOD((Date1-Date2);INT(Datw1-Date2))*24)&" Hours "&MINUTE(Fate1-Date)&" Min";IFERROR((Date1-Date2);"NA"))enter code here`

I think this should do the trick, whatever date you have.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar kind of question, except for me, I needed hours divided by 8, instead of 24, as I needed working days. So I came up with a solution, but it's really really complex to understand because the code looks like a mess, but if you segment them, it's not that hard.

```
=CONCAT(INT(C16*24/8),":",IF(INT((C16-INT(C16))*24)<10,CONCAT("0",INT((C16-INT(C16))*24)),INT((C16-INT(C16))*24)),":",IF(MINUTE(C16)<10,CONCAT("0",MINUTE(C16)),MINUTE(C16)))
```

- Note that I have used "**8**" to divide the hours by **8** because I needed working hours. So you can neglect that if you do not want it
- I needed to display the result as "**4:09:08**" rather than "**4:9:8**". (This is in "Days:Hours:Minutes" format). That's why I have used extra **IF()** and **CONCAT()** functions inside.