# Day/Time Difference VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I'm trying to figure out the time difference between data in Column K and J. I need to know how long it took for data to be updated by the amount of days it took, hours, or minutes and am using those columns. I also want to get the average amount of time only if the names in Column A match and enter that information in Column N. This is what I have so far for the first part.

`ActiveSheet.Name = "Raw Data"
Range("M2:M").Value = ("K2:K-J2:J" > 1) + ("d:hh:mm")`

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This should get the results you want. The [With ... End With block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx) is used to save having to write `Worksheets("Raw Data")` all the time. Anything within the block which starts with a `.` refers to `Worksheets("Raw Data")`

The formula was adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7929360/2127508) but modified to allow for more than 31 days. We then use the [FillDown method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838404(v=office.15).aspx) to copy the formula in cell M2 down to the same row as the last used cell in column K. The references in the formula adjust automatically to point to the correct row

*edit:* updated to calculate average elapsed time for each name listed in column A. This is more complicated because we can't directly average the values we put in column M because we have converted them into a text format. I've chosen to use column Z to hold the numeric time values which we need. You could choose any other unused column and you could hide the column so it doesn't display.

The last used row is stored in a variable because we need to use it in a couple of different places. The numeric difference between columns K and J is stored in column Z. The text value in column M is then calculated from the value in column Z.

Finally, the average in column N is calculated using the [AVERAGEIF function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/AVERAGEIF-function-ff3c70f9-5afe-4d3e-87d4-717187f98c20?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB). This looks through all the used rows in column A, finds those with the same name as the current row and then averages all the values from column Z for any matching rows.

One important point to note: all of the formulas in column N will need to be rewritten if any rows are added or deleted. This is because the last row value stored in those formulas will become incorrect if rows are added or deleted

```
With Worksheets("Raw Data")
  Dim lngLastUsedRow As Long
  lngLastUsedRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

  .Range("Z2").Formula = "=K2-J2"
  .Range("Z2:Z" & lngLastUsedRow).FillDown

  .Range("M2").Formula = "=FLOOR(Z2,1)&"":""&TEXT(Z2,""hh:mm"")"
  .Range("M2:M" & lngLastUsedRow).FillDown

  .Range("N2").Formula = "=AVERAGEIF(A$2:A$" & lngLastUsedRow & ",A2,Z$2:Z$" & lngLastUsedRow &")"
  .Range("N2:N" & lngLastUsedRow).FillDown
End With
```

Comment: That worked, however it does't address the 2nd part about the average amount of time if the names match in column A and that time is entered in Column N

Comment: Need more info on "if the names match in column A". Do you mean the same name appearing in different rows of column A or do you mean the name in column A matching a name in a different column?

Comment: I apologize. I mean the same name appearing in different rows of Column A.

Comment: Question. How would I build on this code? For example. Say that I want to find the average time by the matching names in Column A and the matching jobs task in Column B. Where in the code would I add that last part?

Comment: To get the average time for the names in column B then duplicate the last 2 lines immediately before the `End With`. Change the destination column from "N" to whatever column you want to use and change the references in the "AVERAGEIF" formula from "A" to "B". So if we were using column O: `.Range("O2").Formula = "=AVERAGEIF(B$2:B$" & lngLastUsedRow & ",B2,Z$2:Z$" & lngLastUsedRow &")"` and then `.Range("O2:O" & lngLastUsedRow).FillDown`. If you wanted to show the combined average by name and jobs task then that would be better suited to a pivot table

Comment: That's great! Can I create a pivot table using code and fill it with the data I'm getting form this code?

Comment: You can create pivot tables with code but Microsoft say: "Because PivotTable report programming can be complex, it’s generally easiest to record PivotTable report actions and then revise the recorded code" [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff837611.aspx). You might want to try that and then post a new question if anything doesn't work

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks for the reference. I'm having an issue with the `#DIV/0!` showing for cells that didn't have data to average. How do I get the cells to be blank or to ignore the error and go to the next cell?

Comment: I searched everywhere and found that this worked best. `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).ClearContents`

Thanks for the help!