# Format decimal number as hours and minutes

Tags: windows, excel-2010

I have e.g. this number 10.75. I would like to format it as 10:45 as in hh:mm. But, when I select this cell formatting it becomes 17:45. How can I reach the goal and at the same time support negavtive numbers as if I had -5.25, which then would be -5:15?

It would be nice if the solution still supported conditional cell formatting so that I can use the gradient formatting based on the value.

Do you have ny suggestions for a solution? I need it for an hour registration scheme where I have a cell telling if you have worked to little or too many hours.

Thanks

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/75618

Answer (score 1):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

=LEFT(A5,FIND(".",A5,1)-1)&":"& TEXT(ROUND(--MID(A5,FIND(".",A5),9999)*60,0),"00")

For example:

[image]

Comment: Sorry if I din't explaint it too well. The thing is that I wan't to be able to add conditional formatting of the B column values, with the gradient formatting between minimum and maximum values.

Answer (score 0):

To convert your decimal to a time divide it by 24 and then format that as `hh:mm`, or as desired. This will allow you to add a gradient, as you mentioned in a comment. [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oYwj.png), column B is formatted as `hh:mm`. (I can't embed images yet.)

If you have hours that are more than 24 it will roll to the next day, `25.00` will be `1:00`, `27.50` will be `3:30`, and so on. If this this is not desired, consider formatting as "dd:hh:mm". See answer by brettdj on  [Format a time span as a number of days, hours and minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929058/format-a-time-span-as-a-number-of-days-hours-and-minutes) for how to do this for more than 31 days.

In order to avoid `####` overflow error from a negative time, be sure you are using the 1904 date system. (For help in doing that see [ExcelTips, "Displaying Negative Times"](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T006239_Displaying_Negative_Times.html))