# How do I format the difference of two dates as Number of days, hours, minutes in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929058/format-a-time-span-as-a-number-of-days-hours-and-minutes.).  In that post, formula-based suggestions were made. Unfortunately, those will not work for what I need:

I have a pivot table that contains fractional days, ie. 35.39375 days or 28.32361111 days. I wish to format those numbers as 35 09:27 and 28 07:46, respectively, (in #days, hours, minutes). As well, I'd like to format their row and column totals similarly. And I need to do it in VBA.

Setting the pivot table cell formatting to .NumberFormat = "d hh:mm" does not work as the number of days will be truncated, since they will generally exceed 31 days.

I am using EXCEL 2007.

ADDENDUM:

I thank all people who have suggested formula-based approaches. Those do not work when specifying number formats within VBA for a pivot table. For instance, the following code is faulty because it will cause the numbers of days that exceed 31 to be truncated. The nature of the .NumberFormat specification does not allow formula-based formats either (at least, not that I can see):

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Durations")
      .
      .
      .
    .AddDataField .PivotFields("Duration"), "Count of Duration", xlCount
    With .PivotFields("Count of Duration")
        .Caption = "Sum of Duration"
        .Function = xlSum
        .NumberFormat = "d hh:mm"  <<===  This will cause the number of days to be truncated.
    End With
      .
      .
      .
With
```

Comment: Did you mean 35 09:27 not 4 09:27? As that is truncated

Comment: Perhaps look into [`Convert`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Convert-times-614932f8-bf0d-4993-8e54-4612cd57334f). For example, `=Convert(.5,"day","hour")` evaluates to `12`. Using `.75` evaluates to `18`. ...and `18:00` is 6 PM.

Comment: You can use `=INT(A1)&TEXT(A1, " hh:mm")` but that loses the numerical value of hte original.

Comment: I'm trying to combine the two, but say `35.39375` is in `D20`, `=CONVERT(MID(D20,SEARCH(".",D20),LEN(D20)),"day","hr")` returns `9.45`.  If you then run `=Convert(.45,"hr","mn")` you get `27`, combining the two gets you `9:27`...

Comment: Yes, thank you.  It's 35 09:27 indeed.  Corrected it in the original post.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations about using the formulas, but it doesn't help me when using it in VBA while specifying a number format for pivot table entries.

Comment: maybe `0` or `#` or `?` instead of `d` - `.NumberFormat = "0 hh:mm"`

Comment: The format "0 hh:mm" won't work either. That causes an error because Excel uses the "0" format for numbers (integers, reals, doubles), while it uses "hh:mm" when it expects dates. Indeed, the runtime error is "Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the PivotField class." That also goes for using "#" or "?".

Comment: then it seems like it will have to be a [calculated field](http://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-calculated-field.html) with Excel formula

Comment: I do not believe it is possible. A possible solution would be to create two new calculated fields:  `INT_Days` and `MOD_Days` (with the formula being the obvious).  Format `MOD_Days` as `[hh:mm]`.  You may have to live with seeing hours > 24 in your Grand Totals.  Otherwise you may have to write a VBA routine (not a pivot table) to precisely display the results as you want -- still won't be numbers, though.

Comment: Slai, that's an intriguing suggestion.  I'll explore it. But that will be next week, seeing it is late here.  :-)

Comment: Ron Rosenfeld, as an indirect solution, it is of course possible to generate the pivot table with no formatting, and then generate a separate table (not a pivot one) where I refer to each entry of the pivot table and then use the formula-based formats that have been suggested. I was hoping for a more elegant solution that wouldn't involve an intermediate step.

Comment: @BrunoRepetto Another method that might work are the `Calculated Fields` that I mentioned.

Comment: I have now tried the calculate fields suggestion, and it does not work well.  While I can create a calculated field using a formula like "=int(Duration) & text(Duration,"hh:mm"), the result is not formatted like that at all, remaining formatted as "General". But now, the totals for columns and rows are completely screwed up.

Comment: I guess there is no direct (i.e., elegant one-step) solution to this problem, so I will have to resort to the indirect method of creating a secondary non-pivot table that formats the results from every cell in the original pivot table.

Answer (score 1):

Date types in Excel (and VBA) are already stored as days.[fractional days].  All you need to do is format it.

VBA:

```
foo = 35.39375
Debug.Print Int(foo) & " " & Format$(foo - Int(foo), "hh:nn") 'Prints 35 09:27
```

Formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(INT(A1), TEXT(A1, " hh:mm"))
```

Comment: I know all about Date types. This will not help me when specifying a format for a pivot table in VBA.