How to get the number of Days, difference between time from two timestamp values in Excel
I have two timestamp values wherein I need to calculate the number of days and time difference between two values for our time in motion activity. I tried different formulas but it's getting the error of #VALUE!
Formulas I have tried: H2-G2; TEXT(H2-G2,"dd"); TEXT(H2-G2,"hh"); TEXT(H2-G2,"mm"); TEXT(H2-G2,"ss")
Appreciate you expert help on this. Thanks in advance!
enter image description here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929058/format-a-time-span-as-a-number-of-days-hours-and-minutes?rq=2

Hi I am still getting the same error #VALUE! I tried all the formula shared from the link you share. I am not sure on where the error could be.
